# if command fails, run different function

Tags: matlab, matrix, eigenvalue

I'm working with large sparse matrices and small sparse matrices.

Now, the `eig` command doesn't work with sparse matrices (when using `sprand`) so I must use `eigs`.

But I have a script that needs to use both depending on what matrix I'm using. I could have two identical scripts, one with `eig` the other `eigs` (and 5,6 <=> N-1,N) but I'd like to know how to combat this.

Here is the start of my script.

```
f=eigs(A);  % was eig    
figure(1)
semilogy(res) %

convfact = abs(f(5))/abs(f(6));   % 5,6 was N-1 and N respectively
hold on 
semilogy(convfact.^(1:k),'r--')
```

I'd also like to point out, for when I'm using the `eig` command, as the comment in the code says, the 5 and 6 was the N-1 and N. But obviously MATLAB can't find these values on a 0000x0000 matrix so I must use the 5th and 6th that `eigs` provides.

Any advice on solving this will be great, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking. But have you tried using an `if` statement to test what kind of matrix you have, and then use the corresponding command? From your title it seems like this can also be dealt with using a `try-catch` block but that is probably not the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a simple if/else block?

```
if issparse(A)
    f = eigs(A);
else
    f = eig(A);
end
```